# Preserve checked items listview filter

Tags: android

I have a listview witch supports multiple selections (check boxes).I also have a filter that when i type text in a edit it sorts the listview.

The problem is when I type something and my list gets filtered if I selected a item and then I search another string using the filter it appers checked a diffrent item.

How can I preserve the checked items regardless any filter that I apply to the ListView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to maintain the state of CheckBox manually due to the recycling behaviour of ListView. I had already written a blog for the same explaining how you can manage that.

[`ListView with CheckBox Scrolling Issue`](http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)